# MapBox GL custom markers with symbol layer

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-marker

I am trying to cluster custom markers in MapBox GL JS but I cannot figure out how to get a custom marker image from a url into the symbol layer? It either does not work or no markers show up at all.  How is it done? I need to know how to use a custom image from a url with the symbol layer. Thank you very much.

```
map.addSource('parcelpoints', {
        type: 'geojson',        
        data: geojson,
        cluster: true,
        clusterMaxZoom: 14, // Max zoom to cluster points on
        clusterRadius: 50 // Radius of each cluster when clustering points (defaults to 50)
    });

    map.addLayer({
        id: 'clusters',
        type: 'circle',
        source: 'parcelpoints',
        filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
        paint: {
            // Use step expressions (https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/#expressions-step)
            // with three steps to implement three types of circles:
            //   * Blue, 20px circles when point count is less than 100
            //   * Yellow, 30px circles when point count is between 100 and 750
            //   * Pink, 40px circles when point count is greater than or equal to 750
            'circle-color': [
                'step',
                ['get', 'point_count'],
                '#51bbd6',
                100,
                '#f1f075',
                750,
                '#f28cb1'
            ],
            'circle-radius': [
                'step',
                ['get', 'point_count'],
                20,
                100,
                30,
                750,
                40
            ]
        }
    });

    map.addLayer({
        id: 'cluster-count',
        type: 'symbol',
        source: 'parcelpoints',
        filter: ['has', 'point_count'],
        layout: {
            'text-field': '{point_count_abbreviated}',
            'text-font': ['DIN Offc Pro Medium', 'Arial Unicode MS Bold'],
            'text-size': 12
        }
    });   

        map.addLayer({
        id: 'unclustered-point',
        type: 'symbol',
        source: 'parcelpoints',
        filter: ['!has', 'point_count'],
        'layout': {
         'visibility': 'visible',
         'icon-image':  { url: "marker.svg" }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to:

- load the external image with a specific ID, via `map.loadImage()`.
- add the image with a specific ID, via [`map.addImage(https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/map/#map#loadimage)`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#addimage).

There is a worked example here: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/add-image/

```js
// If the style's sprite does not already contain an image with ID 'kitty',
// add the image 'cat-icon.png' to the style's sprite with the ID 'kitty'.
map.loadImage('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/60/Cat_silhouette.svg/400px-Cat_silhouette.svg.png', (error, image) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    if (!map.hasImage('kitty')) map.addImage('kitty', image);
});
```

To include your loaded image in a symbol layer will look something like:

```js
map.addLayer({
    'id': 'clusters',
    'type': 'circle',
    'source': 'parcelpoints',
    'filter': ['has', 'point_count'],
    'icon-image': 'kitty',
    ...
```

There is no support for directly loading symbol images from URLs.

Comment: what about loading multiple images?

Comment: You need to use a loop.